# How to set QML's Rotation angle property as a changing variable

Tags: qt, qml

I have the following QML code in main.qml :

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    onBeforeRendering: Work.start()

    Connections{
        target: Work
        onResult: res.text = r
    }

    Text{
        id: res
    }

    Rectangle{
        id: rect
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        height: 300
        width: 300
        color: "lightblue"
        radius: 300

        Rectangle{
            id:needle
            color: "black"
            height: 150
            width: 2
            x: 150
            y: 150
            transform: Rotation { origin.x: 0; origin.y: 0; axis { x: 0; y:0 ; z: 1 } angle: 30}
            smooth: true;
        }
    }
}
```

Which simulates a clock or a gauge, and I also have a C++ function connected to the "onResult" event that displays a changing value in the Text{id: res}. Everything works well.

What I would like to add to this is a way to hook up the result Rotation angle property to the "r" result within Connections as the rotation angle.

I thought that adding the following would make it work but I had no luck:

```
Connections{
    target: Work
    onResult: needle.angle = r
}

    Rectangle{
        property double angle: 0
        id:needle
        color: "black"
        height: 150
        width: 2
        x: 150
        y: 150
        transform: Rotation { origin.x: 0; origin.y: 0; axis { x: 0; y:0 ; z: 1 } angle: angle }
        smooth: true;
    }
```

I'm not getting any errors or anything, so I know I'm not hooking things up the right way. I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: what is `Work`? At what point in time does it not work?

Comment: Is the registered class that has the signal that provided the "r" value. So, "engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("Work", &cw);"

Comment: Problem is probably due to angle:angle. Try angle: needle.angle

Comment: @TonyClifton: I think you are right. But I think the usage of `beforeRendering` migh also be problematic. If there is nothing new to render, it won't be called. So, if by some chance, the result is the same for two consecutive calls, it won't be called anymore.

Comment: Thanks @TonyClifton, your answer worked! I did not know i had to be that specific since the angle variable is withing the rectangle to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use rotation property?

```
Connections {
    target: Work
    onResult: needle.rotation = r
}
```

Comment: What about the rivaling `Rotation {...}` and the `rotation`-property? Will there be a winner? Will both be applied?